# Merge ancestor state with component state to enable joint state update via updater functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component with props like `data`, `setData`, and also internal state. I need to `setData` in the same event as `setState`. However, both state changes need knowledge of the other's current state.

```
<Ancestor>
...a lot of intermediate stuff
<DataContext.Consumer>
{([data, setData]) => (
  <Child data={data} setData={setData}/>
)}
</DataContext.Consumer>
</Ancestor>

const Child = ({data, setData}) => {
  let [state, setState] = useState({"foo": "bar"});
  const onUpdate = (e) => {
    setState((currentState) => {/* requires currentData */});
    setData((currentData) => {/* requires currentState */});
  }
}
```

Ways I know of to do this:

- Hoist the state up: this works, but I don't like doing it. I am doing this right now with a reducer, but for the sake of this question, this isn't an option.
- Do it in multiple(?) renders using `useEffect` to sync global and local state. This is complicated, and I've seen people describe it as an antipattern.
- Use `useMemo` to "detach" the component from the props, then handle the combined state in the component and update global state whenever the state change calls for it. (requires calling `setData` from within a state updater function, which seems bad).

What I'm actually trying to do: A form with a variable set of inputs, each of which has a "data state". All such data states are managed together as they are serialized together to a special binary format. For a given child ie. a specific input, how do I manage state together with the global state?

For example, in a custom tag input, when Enter is pressed, I want to both set the input component's edit mode, and also set the global data state to add the newly created tag. In this case, each state update depends on information about the other update's "current state".